# Why is the function $f$ undefined for $x=1$ when $f(x) = \log_x x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The Symbolab graphing calculator tells me that the function $f$ such that :

$$f(x) = \log_x x$$

is undefined for $x=1$.

But suppose that $n = \log_11$

Then  $1$ to the $n$th power  is equal to $1$ (in virtue of the definition of a logarithm), and it seems to me there is a number $n$ satisfying the condition, namely the number $1$, so the ordered pair $(1,1)$ should belong to the function $f$.

So what did I miss?

Comment: You can't take the logarithm in base 1. The logarithm in base $a$ is defined as $L_a(x) = \frac{\ln(x) } {\ln(a) }$; you're dividing by zero when $a = 1$.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Ah, now I see. That was a huge typo. it is not that I didn't answer: it is that I wrote a nonsense. I shall delete all that now, thanks.

Comment: It should have been: by *definition*, the base of a logarithm must be positive and different from one.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I had in mind! I didn't realize that you mistyped; I thought you were just saying 'strictly positive' in a roundabout way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just as well claim that $\log_1 1=2$, because $1^2=1$.

The function $\log_1 x$ is not well defined, because it is supposed to be the inverse of function $1^x$, but this function isn't invertible, even on its image.

Answer (score 0):

Answer redacted because the question has been changed since I answered.

> What is the actual message that the calculator gives you? $f(x) = log_b x$ where $b = 1$ is a valid function only if the domain of $f$ is the set containing a single integer, 1. That's a fine domain but not as common as say, the set of all integers or all real numbers. In those cases, your function would not be a valid function, as there exist some elements of the domain set (eg: 2) that are not mapped to anything in the codomain. It might be that your calculator is interpreting your definition $f$ to be acting on a larger domain than the set just containing 1, in which case, it fails to be a function.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Type `$\log_b x$` to obtain $\log_b x$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.